# Reload after effect animation onclick

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I am attempting to replay an after effects animation using an onclick event in HTML, but not sure how to go about it.  The animation is in it's own div.

I dont want to reload the whole page, just the animation
I was thinking maybe trying some javascript.

```
        $(function() {
        document.getElementById("ANAnimation").onclick = function () {

        }
    })
```

I was thinking some javascript maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can use Callback() functions to repeat the same animation.
Following is the example in jQuery -

```
$("#element").animate({
  // stuff to animate
}, function() {
  // callback function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two options

a) create the node again animate1

b) you can use a css class and reasign it with a short delay. (setTimeout) animate2

```js
function animate1(el) {
  var newEl = el.cloneNode(true);
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(newEl, el);
}
function animate2(el) {
  el.className = '';
  setTimeout(function(){el.className = 'myAnimation'}, 100);
}
```

```css
@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

.myAnimation {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="AnimationA" class="myAnimation" onClick="animate1(this)">Solution A</div>
<br />
<div id="AnimationB" class="myAnimation" onClick="animate2(this)">Solution B</div>
```